# Continu after error event Node.js Webkit

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

My app aim to scan a proxy list.
When i have a dead proxy the error event is call but the callback or the end event is never call, why ?

```
    var file = e.dataTransfer.files[i].path;
    content = fs.readFileSync(file, "UTF-8");
    var lines = content.split("\n");
    var nb = 0;
    async.each(lines, function(line, callback) {

        var arr = line.split(":");
        http.get({host: arr[0], port: arr[1], path: "http://www.google.fr", agent: false}, function(res, req) {
            if(res.statusCode == 200){
                el.className = '';
                el.innerHTML = arr[0] + ':' + arr[1] + '\n';
                nb = nb+1;
            }
            callback();
        }).on('error', function(e) {
            console.error(arr[0] + ':' + arr[1]);
        }).on('end', function(e) {
            console.error('End event nerver load...');
        });   
    },function(){
        el.className = '';
        el.innerHTML = 'Scan terminé. ' + nb + ' Proxy fonctionnels';
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using the async library.

The iterator you passed to `async.each` requires that you call the callback regardless of whether there's an error or not. If you don't call the callback, async will assume that the operation is still running and will wait forever.

When you encounter an error, you should call the callback and pass the error as the first parameter.

So here's an example of what I mean. I've added `callback(e);` to your error event handler.

```
    }).on('error', function(e) {
        console.error(arr[0] + ':' + arr[1]);
        callback(e);
    }).on('end', function(e) {
```

Comment: Thank's but if i call the callback the each loop will be stop ? i want to continu the iteration, even if i get an error. i want to parse each ip of the file before stop

Comment: If you want to continue iterating without terminating on error, just call the callback without the error. `callback();`